# React keyboard event also fires a SyntheticBaseEvent

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to listen on keypresses (namely Shift+A) in react app. I have set up an event listener  but whenever I press Shift+A the event seems to fire twice, once as a `KeyboardEvent` and the second time as a `SyntheticBaseEvent`. This results in the callback function being called twice.

```
class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
     
        this.handleKey = this.handleKey.bind(this);

        this.myDiv = React.createRef();       
        
    }

    componentDidMount() {

        this.myDiv.current.addEventListener('keydown', this.handleKey);
        this.myDiv.current.focus();
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        this.myDiv.current.removeEventListener('keydown', this.handleKey);
    }

    
    ...
    

    handleKey(key){
        if (key.key === "A"){
            this.callback()
            console.log(key)
        }
    }

  render() {
      return (
          <div className={"App"} tabIndex={"0"} onKeyDown={this.handleKey} ref={this.myDiv}>
            
          </div>
      )
    }
}
```

Comment: Reactjs uses syntheticevents . please refer to:  https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#keyboard-events

why are you trying to use standard eventlisteners here?

Comment: @Michael I just started learning React and so didn't know that it had its own event system. If you post some code using the synthetic events that solves this problem I'll mark it as the answer.

Comment: just use them  :)